# Extrude cylinder vertex straight in mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude

How do I extrude my cylinder using a mirror modifier to extrude perfectly straight to form a circle at the top instead of closing out and forming a center bridge?

[image]

I tried changing the orientational to normal and using other origin points, but not sure how to do it properly.

I want it to extrude perfectly together so it forms a circle.

If i use clipping it forms a oval shape
[image]

Update: My only solution was to extrude + scale using clipping, then use the loop cut add on and choose circle.

Is there not an easier way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose *3D Cursor* in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel and put the 3D cursor at the center of your circle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: when I do that it extrudes in the center, except it's along the z-axis so from top view it looks good, but on side view it extrudes downwards

Comment: are you sure that the 3D cursor is correctly placed? please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: oh i was but my object was above on the z axis and that's why it was tryin to move downwards

Comment: the only issue is if I want to scale the top part of my cylinder the same way then that causes issues

Comment: what do you mean? if you want to scale both the top and bottom edge at the same time, as Kuboa explains, constraint on the Z axis with Shift Z

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with a half-cylinder as base mesh, you can choose *3D Cursor* as the pivot point (with 3D Cursor at the center of your cylinder) and extrude, then scale. It starts extruding downwards at an angle at first, but you can fix that by pressing <kbd>Shift+Z</kbd> to exclude Z from the transformation:

[image]

If you're working with a full cylinder as base mesh, you can leave your pivot at *Median Point* (*3D Cursor* would also work) but select the whole circle before extruding:

[image]